# PayPal "Pay with Credit Card" and Item description

Tags: paypal

I have a few questions regarding using PayPal.
The first image is from an existing website, while the second is from a sandboxed Express Checkout test.

Differences between the two:

1. On the left side, there is an item description and quantity.
2. On the bottom right, notice it is Pay with my Credit Card instead of Create a PayPal account.

How do I achieve 1. and 2.? What APIs do I use?

Take note that my site has potentially many items for sale, and it is impossible for me to manually create buttons for each one.

**Edited: Ok I just found the answer to 1.: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/**

For 2., the existing website actually prompts for details such as name, and address before redirecting to the PayPal site. When I click on "Pay with Credit Card", the details input earlier do show up on the PayPal form. I also notice the existing site can accept direct credit card payments, which seem to me it is using at least a Payment Pro solution. Is that why it can achieve 2.? 
How do I achieve that? Do I use the AdaptiveAccount API to create an account on behalf of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order get the credit card section to display by default instead of the option to pay with a PayPal account, you need to pass over to additional variables in your SetExpressCheckout API call.

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole  
LANDINGPAGE-Billing
```